# Can older version of WSP file deploy on latest version of SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I developed my solution on 
**"14.0.4762.1000"** and production server has higher version than development. According to my little knowledge, in share point, previous version solution(wsp) can be deployed on higher version of SharePoint, but my administrator don't agree on it.

Can any body share his expert opinion on it!

Answer (score 0):

As long as its the same major version (SharePoint 2010 in your case) you can install the solution package.